# Nonidentity Multipliers of Constraint Equations for Location Attributes in IOS Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

According to the [Apple Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1):
*You cannot use a nonidentity multiplier (a value other than 1.0) with location attributes*.

If I understand the so-called nonidentity multiplier correctly, the multiplier should always be 1.0 when setting up a constraint for the location attribute. But I tried in Xcode and found the multiplier could be any positive number(int or floating). Check the screenshot below for my testing.

[image: screenshot]

Is it that I understood the above rule specified in the Apple Guide incorrectly or that I modified the multiplier value in a wrong way in Xcode?

Comment: Does it run properly on the device?

Comment: @Malik yes, it ran properly

Comment: Then it seems that their Documentation may be outdated. Either that, or it might have some edge cases that Apple wants to avoid

Answer (score 0):

It is a rule set by Apple. It simply means with size attribute you can add multiplier other than 1 also (like 2, 1.2, etc) because sometimes you want size to be equal, double or proportional to the relative view. Location is used for specify location of an attribute with respect to relative view. So, you don't need a multiplier here. But still you can use it which might gives you some weird result. You cannot use 0 also other than in NotAnAttribute.